# keyExists cannot be resolved to a variable - Java

Tags: java, registry

I'm doing a Java program and I did a method that checks if the key in the Windows registry exists, the method looks like this

```
public static void keyExists(String key) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  
  int returnValue = -1;
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + key);
  process.waitFor();
  returnValue = process.exitValue();
  
  if(returnValue==0) {
      
      boolean keyExists = true;
      
  }
  
  if(returnValue==1) {
      
      boolean keyExists = false;
      
  }
  
  return keyExists;
  
}
```

but the Eclipse IDE gives me the error "keyExists cannot be resolved to a variable" in

```
return keyExists;
```

I am beginner :)

Comment: Those declarations aren't visible outside their enclosing scopes. You need to declare it ahead of the tests and only assign in in the test blocks.

Comment: Your function has a void return value; it should be boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared variable keyExists only in if blocks. The compiler won't let you compile that program because there is a case when you will have a value different from 0 or 1.
And also you don't return type of your function.
Please, try out that

```
public static boolean keyExists(String key) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int returnValue = -1;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + key);
        process.waitFor();
        returnValue = process.exitValue();

        return returnValue == 0;
    }
```

Comment: @alfie I am returning boolean in that case, not an integer.